# How do I extract the matrix from an density matrix equation?

Tags: matrix, expression-manipulation

I have a density matrix equation and I wish to put it in the form of a matrix.

For example, if I have:

$$\rho =Ax_{1}x_{1}+Bx_{1}x_{2}+Cx_{2}x_{1}+Dx_{2}x_{2}$$

Copy-and-paste version

```
ρ = 
  A Subscript[x, 1]^2 + B Subscript[x, 1] ** Subscript[x, 2] +
  C Subscript[x, 2] ** Subscript[x, 1] + D Subscript[x, 2]^2
```

I want the result to be:

\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}

Is there a simple way to do it for an n by n matrix?

Comment: If you really want non-commutative multiply, you have written the expression for $rho$ incorrectly.

Comment: You are right, I just edited it to (what I think) is the good expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

It was not clear from your original question that you were using noncommutative variables. In that case, the input needs to indicate this. In particular, x^2 is used for commutative multiplication, so it would be better to use `x**x` instead. So:

```
ρ = a Subscript[x, 1]**Subscript[x, 1] + b Subscript[x, 1]**Subscript[x, 2] + c Subscript[x, 2]**Subscript[x, 1] + d Subscript[x, 2]**Subscript[x, 2];
```

Then, you can use [`Coefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient):

```
Map[
    Coefficient[ρ, #]&,
    Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, {Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2]}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}]
]
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}}

**Original answer**

You can use [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays):

```
ρ = A Subscript[x, 1]^2 + B Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] + C Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 1] + D Subscript[x, 2]^2

Normal @ CoefficientArrays[ρ, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}][[3]] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  A & B+C \\
>  0 & D \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: While this is very close to what I want, is there a way to do something about the B+C? (Note that the order of x1 and x2 matter) While this is easily solvable for a 2x2 matrix, it becomes really hard to deal with for big matrices (I have to deal with 50x50 matrixes, and maybe more)